# How to solve the issue with Java fx depreciated threads that make GUI freeze?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am writing a project in Java Fx - washing machine.

It's working pretty well but I have some issues with threads. My IDE shows that my used thread methods like `suspend()` and `resume()` are depreciated.

I guess it is the issue as my washing machine needs to rotate the clothes but it freezes totally randomly. Sometimes it gets back to rotating and sometimes it doesn't and I have to restart the application.

I understand that it might be a bit of code to check (~100 lines) but you can `ctrl+f` through it to find `resume()` and `suspend()`. Logic of the program is pretty easy and I have left comments on what is happening.

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import java.io.File;
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane pranko;
    @FXML
    private Label score;
    private Thread thread;
    private Boolean on = false;
    private int rotations = 0;
    //sound set-up
    String musicFile = "snap.mp3";
    Media sound = new Media(new File(musicFile).toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
    @FXML
    private void initialize() throws InterruptedException {
        //Start/Stop button initialize
        Circle circle = new Circle(25);
        button.setShape(circle);
        button.setMinSize(50,50);
        //LCD screen set-up
        score.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green;" +
                "-fx-background-color: black");
        score.setText("START");
        //adding shadow around the button
        DropShadow dropShadow = new DropShadow();
        dropShadow.setRadius(5);
        dropShadow.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        button.setEffect(dropShadow);
        // Rotation and main app logic <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
                        pranko.setRotate(i);
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                score.setText(String.valueOf(rotations));
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            //time between iterations so the rotation could work.
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(5);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    if (rotations == 0) {
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                on = false;
                                //Changing text in button, it's color and shadow
                                button.setText("start");
                                button.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #0cf800");
                                DropShadow dropShadow = new DropShadow();
                                dropShadow.setRadius(5);
                                dropShadow.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                                button.setEffect(dropShadow);
                                //text change in LCD screen
                                score.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;" +
                                        "-fx-background-color: black");
                                score.setText("END");

                            }
                        });
                        thread.suspend();
                    } else {
                        rotations -= 1;

                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
        thread.suspend();
    }

    @FXML
    private void toggle() throws InterruptedException {
        if (on) {
            on = false;
            thread.suspend();
            //changing text in button, it's color and shadow
            button.setText("start");
            button.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #0cf800");
            DropShadow dropShadow = new DropShadow();
            dropShadow.setRadius(5);
            dropShadow.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            button.setEffect(dropShadow);
        } else {
            thread.resume();
            on = true;
            //changing text in button, it's color and shadow
            button.setText("stop");
            button.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red");
            DropShadow dropShadow = new DropShadow();
            dropShadow.setRadius(5);
            dropShadow.setColor(Color.RED);
            button.setEffect(dropShadow);
            rotations = 10; //set full rotation count
            //changing color of text in LCD and the background
            score.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green;" +
                    "-fx-background-color: black");
        }
    }
}
```

Full project package is available here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/149R-Fnss7NymqJ_IGUKL4DkfE6pUtxmW/view?usp=sharing
Virus scan:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/d70d900c3a75dbc58f089358d33b275046ff5879e7aa16df427b09ae3cb96093/detection

It took me a lot of time already so I am asking for help. Every help will be rewarded.

There has to be a way to make it working normally with threads or in some other way

Comment: no external code please - instead provide a [mcve] here.

Comment: My guess would be that you not use `Thread`. Have a look at `Timeline` or something else from the `Animation` API. My other guess is that you should see if using `Platform.runlater` correctly can solve the issue. I would default to something from the `Animation` API.

Comment: Don't use background threads for animation; use the [Animation API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) instead. A `Timeline` is probably the best choice here, though it might also be worth considering a `PauseTransition` or `AnimationTimer`.